# How to convert FormData with file in it to JSON

Tags: json, ajax, form-data

I want to convert a FormData with a single file in it to JSON to send it in ajax
How can i do it ?
I can explain more if you ask

I don't think i can make it otherwise

e.g.

```
form_data = new FormData()
form_data.append('file', e.dataTransfer.files[0])
data = JSON.stringify(form_data)
axios.post('my_route', {
data })
.then( ...)
```

Comment: You mean file upload with other field using ajax?

Comment: I edited the first post. I want to send a file (and other informations) with ajax